# Edit array from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to make a form where I can edit information from an array I get from my database. And then put them in a form with strings so I can edit the values of each category from the database and then send the changed information to the database. When i use this command

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername;$dbname;charset=utf8', 'glitter', 'glitter');
$sql = 'call get_article_info("123456789")';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$printable = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($printable);
```

I get the following array back

```
     (
        [artikel_nr] => 123456789
        [0] => 123456789
        [points] => 50x50 5 
        [1] => 50x50 5 
        [points2] => 50x50 5 
        [2] => 50x50 5 
        [scale] => 1 + 0.75
        [3] => 1 + 0.75
        [energy] => 70
        [4] => 70
        [value] => 5.000
        [5] => 5.000
        [nollan] =>
        [6] =>
        [approved_from] =>
        [7] =>
        [approved_to] =>
        [8] =>
    )
```

Now I would like to put all the info I've got from this array and put it in a form. Then I would be able to edit those informations

The following  SQL : `"call get_article_info("123456789")` as far as I know should be a `select` procedure

Comment: How did you get the array in to the database?

Comment: is the array in one field in the db or it is one column for each item in the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Check it out and try to give us some more information on how do you get the array etc.

Comment: @Script47 i created the array from a already exsiting databse.

Comment: @SupremeDEV I got the array using this code in putty                                 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8', '$username', '$password');
php > $sql = "call hämta_artikel_info('715.703.980')";
php > $result = $db->query($sql);
php > $printable = $result->fetchAll();
php > print_r($printable);

Comment: @AxelGronberg You should first make an good `SELECT` statement that is going to store the selected data in an $variable. Then using your $variable['key'], you will be able to print chosen key of the array. Then give it a new value and make an good `UPDATE` statement that is going to change the data you want to.